# How to get count of divs which have display property block using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
   <div class="divYS" id="dvProductsFilteredd">
                <span class="s">Your Selection:</span>
                <div id="dvFilter-Type" style="display:none">
                    <a class="s roundit" href="javascript:void(0);" id="aFilter-Type" onclick="ResetFilters(1);"></a>
                </div>
                <div id="dvFilter-Category" style="display:none">
                    <a class="s roundit" href="javascript:void(0);" id="aFilter-Category" onclick="ResetFilters(2);"></a>
                </div>
                <div id="dvFilter-Occasion" style="display:none">
                    <a class="s roundit" href="javascript:void(0);" id="aFilter-Occasion" onclick="ResetFilters(3);"></a>
                </div>
                <div id="dvFilter-Supplier" style="display:none">
                    <a class="s roundit" href="javascript:void(0);" id="aFilter-Supplier" onclick="ResetFilters(4);"></a>
                </div>
                  <div id="dvFilter-SortExpression" style="display:none">
                    <a class="s roundit" href="javascript:void(0);" id="aFilter-SortExpression" onclick="ResetFilters(5);"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to get count of sub div's of dvProductsFilteredd which have display property block using JQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check for the `display:block` property explicitly then you can use the filter method

```
$('#dvProductsFilteredd > div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') === 'block';
}).length;
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/8KXQp/1/)**

But if you just want to know the number of visible divs, then you can use the `:visible` selector.

Comment: This answers the question more strictly than the other answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#dvProductsFilteredd').children('div:visible').length
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8KXQp/

Comment: For performance reasons, the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) recommend first using a strict CSS selector and then filtering it out, like so: `$("#dvProductsFilteredd").children("div").filter(":visible").length`.